# How to map attributes of html radiobutton element to asp radiobutton element?

Tags: javascript, html, attributes, radio-button

Html radio button:

```
 <label><input type="radio" name="colorRadio" value="f1">Option 1</label><br>
```

ASP.NET radio button:

```
 <asp:RadioButton ID="RadioButton1" runat="server" />
```

I am trying to apply the following script to an asp radio button:

```
<script type="text/javascript">
       $(function () {
           $("input[type=\"radio\"]").click(function () {
               var thisElem = $(this);
               var value = thisElem.val();
               $(".box").hide();
               $("." + value).show();
               //localStorage:
               localStorage.setItem("option", value);
           });
           //localStorage:
           var itemValue = localStorage.getItem("option");
           if (itemValue !== null) {
               $("input[value=\"" + itemValue + "\"]").click();
           }
       });
         </script>
```

Comment: what is html generated of asp code ? Also what happen when you apply above jquery code to asp radio ?

Comment: Swati Thank you very much! Your question what is html generated of asp code prompt me to view  the RadioButton's attributes in browser and I understood that RadioButton already has a value attribute, so I renamed it. When the above jquery code is applied to asp radio the block will appear.

Comment: So thats working ? any error ?

Comment: Yes it's working. I have added value attribute: <asp:RadioButton ID="RadioButton1" runat="server" value="f1"/>